# It is possible to utilize google search engine directly in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-search

I've been trying to see all day if it's possible to write a web app in C#/asp.net that uses the google search engine. I've been googling about it all day. I don't want the custom search api because I'm not looking to have a search engine search through a site. I want to have my web app pass input to the **basic google web search that search the entire net not a particular site** so I can then parse through the first page of the search results. I put that in bold because it seems like the custom search api is for searching a particular site (my own site) which is **not** what I want to do and yet the only thing I could find. (well for the most part at least) The closest answer I found to my question is this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4082976/5607333 Which might do the trick for me but I don't know how to do that.  How do I send search input to google search and get results using html? (or in my case asp.net) If you think it's the answer to my question can you please post an example of how it's done? I say "think" because I'm not sure it's the answer to what I'm asking.

I hope this question isn't considered a dupe to the question I linked to as  I have been way more specific than it.

Also if this task isn't possible in C#/asp.net but possible in another language can someone please post an example of how it's done in that language or a link to it?

**Update:** I figured out what an easy solution is to this it hit while I was looking at another question similar to my problem. The solution is to edit the url and then i assume you could just concatenate it in C# with the + sign.

**Update: 2** Even though I figured what I specifically was having trouble with at the moment of writing this question I still doesn't why I can't find a google equivalent of this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251020.aspx that's not depreciated. I read an answer to another question on here where someone said it's because that's how they make their money off the ad results but if that's true it still surprises me.

Answer (score -1):

Look this question:

[Adding Google's standard search (not custom) to my website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816721/adding-googles-standard-search-not-custom-to-my-website)

you can use your own XML parser to customize the display for your search users.

with an http request like this:

GET /search?q=bill+material&output=xml&client=test&site=operations 
But it has a limitation on number of requests per day, 500 or 1000 I guess

Comment: Thanks that's part of the answer I was hoping for but not entirely. The op of that question already knew how to send search requests to google and get results which is meat of my question. But also since you mentioned that XML string how would I inject that into asp.net? Could I do this <script="XML">"the string"</script>?